# EEA Family Permit "Date of Arrival" Earliest request?

Tags: visas, england

So I am about to apply the EEA Settlement Permit visa to UK, and i can not find reliable information about the minimum time request for the Date of arrival. I was planning to apply on April and want to arrive july. But alas so many issues and delay in paperwork so i can only apply later middle week of June.

Is it too risky to put my arrival on July? i know schengen visa stated 4 weeks max of date of arrival to apply, and this EEA visa i have no clue, already searching everywhere :(

Comment: To close voters: the visa in question also applies to short-term travel.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can apply if your proposed date of travel is less than three months away.  There is no mention of a three month period on the [government information site](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/eu-settlement-scheme-family-permit).

In most cases, including this one, rules concerning the minimum time between a visa application and arrival are not strict requirements but simply advice.  If you apply after the recommended latest date, your application will not be disqualified automatically, but you might have to postpone your trip.